# How to give API key to Django model

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have to build a web service and API using Django. I was provided with description of models and JSON file with API methods ([here](https://pastebin.com/8YXarxZc)). I have decided to use Django REST framework, but this is first time I am working with an API.

The  field in the described model that is bothering me: 
`api_key = models.CharField(...) #access key to api`.

As I understand, this key needs to be given by me to a model object (in my case it is a model for Printer that prints checks for client and kitchen), and then it must be used for accessing these objects to the API (methods /new_checks/ and /check/). How do I create these keys? Should I just use a random API key generator or there is some instrumental in Django REST framework that I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will suit what you are looking for [djangorestframework-api-key](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-api-key/)

You can add permissions on your api and api keys are stored securely than `CharField` in model

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the following library. Let me help you with a short description of the same. 
**Installation of [djangorestframework-api-key](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-api-key/)**

1. Install djangorestframework-api-key running the following command :
   `pip install djangorestframework-api-key`
2. Add the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # ...,
  'rest_framework',
  'rest_framework_api_key',
]
```

3. Run migrations using `python manage.py migrate`

**Set required permissions:**
`HasAPIKey` permission class requires all clients to provide a valid API key, regardless of whether they provide authentication details. 
 As with every permission class, you can either use them globally:

```
# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey',
    ]
}
```

or view based class

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_api_key.permissions import HasAPIKey

class UserListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (HasAPIKey,)
    # ...
```

**Create and manage API keys :** 
API keys cam be created managed and revoked using the Admin Panel provided by `djangorestframework-api-key` itself.

**Make authorized requests:** 
After enabling the API permissions on your application , clients can make authorized request like below :

```
curl -H 'Api-Token: YOUR_API_TOKEN_HERE' -H 'Api-Secret-Key: YOUR_API_SECRET_KEY_HERE' http://localhost:8000/my-resource/
```

This answer is mostly a short version of the documentation provided [here](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-api-key/). You can have a look the official documentation of it for more detailed explanation and example projects.